# Show image in blade file of laravel

Tags: laravel

I am storing image in `storage/app/safety/`. If I run command `php artisan storage:link` I am getting output  `ERROR  The [public/storage] link already exists.`. I am trying to show image in blade file using below code.

```
->addColumn('image', function ($gasSafety) {
   return '<img src="'.asset("storage/app/safety/{$gasSafety->image}").'" alt="profile Pic" height="200" width="200">';
   })
```

But I can't see image.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Laravel's `php artisan storage:link` command creates a link to `storage/app/public`, not `storage/app/safety`. This means files in `storage/app/safety` won't be directly accessible via the public path.

You can solve issue by moving your images to `storage/app/public/safety`. Then, update your blade file code to:

```
->addColumn('image', function ($gasSafety) {
   return '<img src="'.asset("storage/safety/{$gasSafety->image}").'" alt="profile Pic" height="200" width="200">';
})
```

Comment: Thanks @Jeyhun Rashidov. I was uploading images using this code. 
```
$images = [];
        $files  = $request->file( 'image' );

        if ( $request->hasFile( 'image' ) ) {
            foreach ( $files as $file ) {
                $file->store( 'safety' );
                $images[] = $file->hashName();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Use `$file->store('public/safety');` instead